# "There should be someone at the reception desk"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 1. "There should be someone at the reception desk" (affirmative sentence)

I believe this sentence is correct and also next one.

> 2. "Shouldn´t there be someone at the reception desk?

but what about the 3rd?

> 3. "Should there be someone at the reception desk?

and with must?

> 4. "There must be someone here"  (affirmative sentence)
> 5. "Mustn´t there be someone here?"
> 6. "Must there be someone here?"

Somehow I feel that N°s 3 & 6 are not correct or are they? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The "mandatory, unavoidable" sense of ***must*** is irrelevant to the issue here. Note that *There should be a law against it* is inherently ambiguous. It could either mean the speaker thinks there *ought* to be such a law (regardless of whether there actually is or not), or that the speaker believes there probably ***is*** such a law. Only context will tell you which meaning applies. #3 and #6 are perfectly valid - they just mean slightly different things in most contexts.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, and just to make sure: The six sentences are well constructed then, are they not.

Comment: Your option #5 is extremely unlikely in most contexts - so although it's "well constructed", you should probably avoid starting a question with that particular contracted negation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Should you not give him an answer?

Comment: @SovereignSun: I don't really know *how* to answer this one, since I don't understand what it is about #3 and #6 that make OP feel they're "not correct". Per my second comment, I find #5 at least *slightly* unusual / affected - but offhand I can't say exactly *why,* and apparently OP has no qualms about that one anyway. I kinda hoped someone else (perhaps someone who speaks the same language as OP) would know why he has a problem here, so they'd be better able to explain and resolve any confusion. But maybe I was being over-optimistic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you can do it. Come on. You've almost answered already.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually have more trouble with 6 than 5. I don't have a ton of trouble with either of them but #5 reminds me of something I'd read in a Jane Austin novel... so that makes it a bit archaic... but not necessarily invalid? Maybe that's the affectedness you mention?

Comment: @Catija: Exactly! With a bit of heavy smoothing, [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mustn%C2%B4t+he%2CShouldn%27t+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMust%20not%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShould%20not%20he%3B%2Cc0) (case-sensitive, so it'll mostly pick up just interrogatives as per OP's examples) clearly shows how negated ***should*** has displaced ***must*** for such contexts. But #6 seems fine to me (I equate it with exasperated *Must you make so much noise?*, for example, which is still idiomatic to me).

Answer (score 10):

All of your segments are correct and understandable, intonation and context can be key, here are some possible scenarios for each of them

> 1) There should be someone at the reception desk.
>   *bellhop telling hotel guest to see someone at reception*
>
> 2) Shouldn´t there be someone at the reception desk?
>   *hotel guest telling bellhop wondering why is no one at the reception desk*
>
> 3) Should there be someone at the reception desk?
>   *do we need someone at the reception desk?*
>   *hotel manager asking if it is necessary to have someone at the reception desk*
>   *hotel guest asking why no one is at the reception desk*
>
> 4) There must be someone here!
>   *hotel guest screaming in an empty hotel not being able to find anyone*
>
> 5) Mustn´t there be someone here?
>   *why is nobody here?*
>   *hotel guest asking cab driver when being dropped off at an apparently empty hotel*
>
> 6) Must there be someone here?
>   *why does someone need to be here?*
>   *does someone really need to be here?*

> Should there be someone...

is used when *someone* is not there but is supposed to be there and one is wondering why they are not there.

> Must there be someone...

is used when *someone* is there and one is questioning the necessity of them being there.

Answer (score 3):

> There isn't anyone at the reception desk but there should be.
>
> There is someone at the reception desk, as there should be.
>   --Are you sure there should be someone at the reception desk? Isn't the hotel closed for repairs?
>
> There isn't anyone at the reception desk but there must be.
>
> There is someone at the reception desk as there must be.

These modals don't refer to simple reality but to a desired reality, a supposed reality, an obligatory reality.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a stab at #3 and #6.  Both of them could be used *in specific situations*.

If I was designing a hotel, or developing the staffing plan for a hotel, I could use #3.

> So let's talk about where we'll be stationing employees during the overnight shift.
>
> Should there be someone at the reception desk?
>
> As long as the back-office person is close enough to hear the bell ring, I don't think we need to do that.

If I was in a bad mood and wanted to be left alone, I could use #6.

> Must there be someone here?  I just want to sit in my dressing room alone, without any bodyguards or makeup artists or you other people who are always hanging around!!!
>
> Of course, Ms. Diva, we'll be going.  If you need anything just text me, I'll be waiting outside.

EDIT

I could also use #6 in the 'reception desk' scenario as follows:

> Here's the estimated bill, sir.
>
> Must there be someone at the reception desk?  I've booked the entire hotel for a private party and all of my guests are already here. What's the point of having somebody at the desk - they won't have anything to do!  I don't want to pay for that!

Answer (score 3):

All of the sentences are grammatically correct.

The difference between these sentences...

> 2. Shouldn't there be someone at the reception desk?
> 3. Should there be someone at the reception desk?

... is that Sentence 2 expects a "yes" answer (the speaker thinks there ought to be someone at the desk), while Sentence 3 expresses more uncertainty (the speaker doesn't know whether there should be someone at the desk).

To me as an American speaker, starting a question with "must" sounds somewhat archaic, even though it is technically correct grammar.

Usually a better way to express this meaning is to use "have to" instead of "must":

> Doesn't there have to be someone at the reception desk?
>
> Does there have to be someone at the reception desk?

In the case of these sentences...

> *Must* there be someone at the reception desk?
>
> Does there *have* to be someone at the reception desk?

...the emphasis is often placed on "must" and "have" to express reluctance (the speaker doesn't want there to be someone at the desk).

Comment: "Doesn't there have to be someone at the reception desk?" and "Does there have to be someone at the reception desk?" sounds very unusual and possibly incorrect. Starting with "Must there" or "Mustn't there" may be unusual in American English, but _is_ correct; the Harry Potter series (representing UK English) has many of these.

Comment: I guess there is a big difference between American and British English here then. For a question, we almost *always* use "have to" or "need to" and almost *NEVER* "must".

Comment: Here are examples for [Must there](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=XHkvm6MJepsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=must+there+be+scapegoats&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=must%20there%20be%20scapegoats&f=false) and [Mustn't there](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=tbdZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mustn%27t+there+be%22&dq=%22mustn%27t+there+be%22&redir_esc=y). The latter does seem quite rare.

Comment: I understand that grammatically there is nothing wrong with must/mustn't there. I would note that both of those examples are from pretty formal academic/theoretical books published in the 80s, one of which is actually a translation from a 1960s German work. My point is that in modern, spoken US English, we almost never use it, and it would sound very strange and also very British to us :)

Comment: I was curious so I did a little digging... "Have" and "need" are part of a category called [catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs), meaning verbs that are followed directly by another verb. Many of the verbs in this category, especially when used impersonally or in the 3rd person, e.g. "it requires/seems/looks like/implies/has to/needs to/deserves", use "does" in question form ("Does it require..." vs. "Requires it...").